# glVertexAttribPointer, change vertex attributes layout

Tags: opengl

I'm programming a glsl 1.3+ viewer, and I'll need to change the sources of the shaders often not to delete then and recreate...
But, there is some informations not given in the man of opengl about redefine the vertices attributes layout.

What happens to the previous call to

```
    glVertexAttribPointer( posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
```

when recall it using another posAttrib?
how to "unbind" a shader input variable from the vertex attribute array?
How to make a same posAttrib to point to a different location in the vertex attribute array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question about what happens to previous call to `glVertexAttribPointer`, I believe the attribute pointer just got reassigned by the latest call of `glVertexAttribPointer`.

There is no "unbind" in this usage. You are simply changing the reference, there is no additional memory created. The last input argument is the offset of your supplied `posAttrib` as the VBO. If your `posAttrib` contains vertex coordinate, normal and texture coordinate, then you could do something like the following, assuming you defined a new type `AttributedVertex` with 8 `floats` in it (3 for vertex, 3 for normal, 2 for texture coordinate)

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(AttributedVertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(AttributedVertex), (void *)(3*sizeof(GLfloat));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(AttributedVertex), (void *)(6*sizeof(GLfloat));
```

Your vertex shader should have 3 attributes like

```
attribute vec3 inPosition;
attribute vec3 inNormal;
attribute vec2 inTexCoord;
```

that correspond those vertex attributes.